# Faster solution to compare files in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

file1:

```
chr1    14361   14829   NR_024540_0_r_DDX11L1,WASH7P_468
chr1    14969   15038   NR_024540_1_r_WASH7P_69
chr1    15795   15947   NR_024540_2_r_WASH7P_152
chr1    16606   16765   NR_024540_3_r_WASH7P_15
chr1    16857   17055   NR_024540_4_r_WASH7P_198
```

and file2:

```
NR_024540 11
```

I need find match `file2` in `file1` and print whole `file1 + second column of file2`

So ouptut is:

```
  chr1  14361   14829   NR_024540_0_r_DDX11L1,WASH7P_468 11
chr1    14969   15038   NR_024540_1_r_WASH7P_69 11
chr1    15795   15947   NR_024540_2_r_WASH7P_152 11
chr1    16606   16765   NR_024540_3_r_WASH7P_15 11
chr1    16857   17055   NR_024540_4_r_WASH7P_198 11
```

My solution is very slow in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do

c=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
d=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')

grep $c file1 | awk -v line="$d" -v OFS="\t" '{print $1,$2,$3,$4"_"line}' >> output


 done < file2
```

I am prefer FASTER any bash or awk solution. Output can be modified, but need keep all the informations (order of column can be different).

EDIT:

Right now it looks like fastest solution according @chepner:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r c d; do

grep $c file1 | awk -v line="$d" -v OFS="\t" '{print $1,$2,$3,$4"_"line}' 

done < file2 > output
```

Comment: Are sorted `file1` or/and `file2` somehow ?

Comment: Storing your data in a proper database to support querying the data would be fastest of all.

Comment: Yes they are sorted according sor -k 1V,2 -k 2n,2 , but there is n o problem to sort it for this task and sort back according my requirements.

Comment: @Geroge: The numbers can occur anywhere in file1 or only in last column?

Comment: @chepner thank you for reply. I have no idea to work with database.. Would tell me how to do that? Thank you!

Comment: @Inian thank you. Numbers can occur anywhere. I can fix it later..

Comment: @George - Can you try this solution and let me know the performance - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509226/faster-solution-to-compare-files-in-bash/42509938#42509938

Comment: @Geroge, http://sqlite.org/ might be a good place to start, in terms of finding a lightweight indexed database that will be able to do lookups much, much faster than scanning a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution using `join` and `sed`, Under the assumption that `file1` and `file2` are sorted

```
join <(sed -r 's/[^ _]+_[^_]+/& &/' file1) file2 -1 4 -2 1 -o "1.1 1.2 1.3 1.5 2.2" > output
```

If the output order doesn't matter, to use `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR{d[$1]=$2; next}
    {split($4,v,"_"); key=v[1]"_"v[2]; if(key in d) print $0, d[key]}
' file2 file1
```

you get,

```
chr1 14361 14829 NR_024540_0_r_DDX11L1,WASH7P_468 11
chr1 14969 15038 NR_024540_1_r_WASH7P_69 11
chr1 15795 15947 NR_024540_2_r_WASH7P_152 11
chr1 16606 16765 NR_024540_3_r_WASH7P_15 11
chr1 16857 17055 NR_024540_4_r_WASH7P_198 11
```

Comment: or even this `awk 'FNR==NR{map[$1]=$2; next}{k=$4"_"$5 }(k in map){print $0,map[k]}' file2 FS='[ _]+' file1`

Comment: @Jose Thats awesome, awk solution works like a charm and very very fast! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In a single `Awk` command,

```
awk 'FNR==NR{map[$1]=$2; next}{ for (i in map) if($0 ~ i){$(NF+1)=map[i]; print; next}}' file2 file1

chr1 14361 14829 NR_024540_0_r_DDX11L1,WASH7P_468 11
chr1 14969 15038 NR_024540_1_r_WASH7P_69 11
chr1 15795 15947 NR_024540_2_r_WASH7P_152 11
chr1 16606 16765 NR_024540_3_r_WASH7P_15 11
chr1 16857 17055 NR_024540_4_r_WASH7P_198 11
```

A more readable version in a multi-liner

```
FNR==NR {
    # map the values from 'file2' into the hash-map 'map'
    map[$1]=$2
    next
}
# On 'file1' do
{
    # Iterate through the array map
    for (i in map){
        # If there is a direct regex match on the line with the 
        # element from the hash-map, print it and append the 
        # hash-mapped value at last
        if($0 ~ i){
            $(NF+1)=map[i]
            print
            next
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is better `split($4,v,"_"); key=v[1]"_"v[2]; if(key in map)` instead of `for (i in map) if(match($0,i))`

Comment: Thank you so much, but still to slow - I have cca 600K rows in file1. But nice solution in awk..

Comment: @Geroge: It is the minimalistic `awk` that can be used.

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM.: Agree with yours, but Ed Morton suggests always use the direct `~` match over any match functions

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. wc -l file1 600K and wc -l file2 56K

Comment: @Inian if file2 is very large, then, `for (i in map)` is slow .... this is 56K iteration for each line in file1 .....

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM.: Also my only worry is about the data, your example will work fine as long as key is two words from file2 separated by `_` , a direct regex match is more generic, correct me if i am wrong

Comment: `^1` nice once,  add `next` statement after `print`, looping through array is considerably slower, could have used `(var in array)`

Comment: @AkshayHegde: Please post a more faster approach than mine, if you think it can be done

Comment: `awk 'FNR==NR{map[$1]=$2; next}{split($4,d,/_/); k=d[1]"_"d[2] }(k in map){print $0,map[k]}' file2 file1` or even this better than split `awk 'FNR==NR{map[$1]=$2; next}{k=$4"_"$5 }(k in map){print $0,map[k]}' file2 FS='[ _]+' file1`.
`

Comment: @AkshayHegde As I told in a previous comment to Jose, your key search assumes key is in a fixed pattern. My regex match would make it a bit generic for all matches

Comment: @Inian: Ooops! yes confusing, whether OP looks for exact match or partial match, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

try this -

```
 cat file2
NR_024540 11
NR_024541 12

 cat file11
chr1    14361   14829   NR_024540_0_r_DDX11L1,WASH7P_468
chr1    14361   14829   NR_024542_0_r_DDX11L1,WASH7P_468
chr1    14969   15038   NR_024540_1_r_WASH7P_69
chr1    15795   15947   NR_024540_2_r_WASH7P_152
chr1    16606   16765   NR_024540_3_r_WASH7P_15
chr1    16857   17055   NR_024540_4_r_WASH7P_198
chr1    14361   14829   NR_024540_0_r_DDX11L1,WASH7P_468
chr1    14969   15038   NR_024540_1_r_WASH7P_69
chr1    15795   15947   NR_024540_2_r_WASH7P_152
chr1    16606   16765   NR_024540_3_r_WASH7P_15


awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} substr($4,1,9) in a {print $0,a[substr($4,1,9)]}' file2 file11
chr1    14361   14829   NR_024540_0_r_DDX11L1,WASH7P_468 11
chr1    14969   15038   NR_024540_1_r_WASH7P_69 11
chr1    15795   15947   NR_024540_2_r_WASH7P_152 11
chr1    16606   16765   NR_024540_3_r_WASH7P_15 11
chr1    16857   17055   NR_024540_4_r_WASH7P_198 11
chr1    14361   14829   NR_024540_0_r_DDX11L1,WASH7P_468 11
chr1    14969   15038   NR_024540_1_r_WASH7P_69 11
chr1    15795   15947   NR_024540_2_r_WASH7P_152 11
chr1    16606   16765   NR_024540_3_r_WASH7P_15 11
```

> Performance - (Tested for 55000 records)

```
time awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} substr($4,1,9) in a {print $0,a[substr($4,1,9)]}' file2 file1 > output1

real    0m0.16s
user    0m0.14s
sys     0m0.01s
```

Comment: Everyone inhere has at least once delete his own answer because of a difference of just two seconds....  15 minutes difference is huge even for coincidence. Has happened to all of us.

Comment: @AkshayHegde - Check my Updated Answer and let me know your comment.

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR: `^1` Now its fine, `(var in array) is right method`

Comment: @AkshayHegde - I tried all solution provided by SO members of this question and i found this solution take atleast 60% less time..

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR: try this too `awk 'FNR==NR{map[$1]=$2; next}{k=$4"_"$5 }(k in map){print $0,map[k]}' file2 FS='[ _]+' file1` see how much time it takes

Answer (score 1):

You are starting a lot of external programs unnecessarily. Let `read` split the incoming line from `file2` for you instead of calling `awk` twice. There is also no need to run `grep`; `awk` can do the filtering itself.

```
while read -r c d; do
    awk -v field="$c" -v line="$d" -v OFS='\t' '$0 ~ field {print $1,$2,$3,$4"_"line}' file1
done < file2 > output
```

Comment: Oops: `file` should be the last argument to `awk`, fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much.. Very good to know, how to use read -r c d :) Whne I am playing, I think, that your "read -r c d ..." and my grep is fastest solution..

Answer (score 1):

If the searched string is always the same length (`length("NR_024540")==9`):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} (i=substr($4,1,9)) && (i in a){print $0, a[i]}' file2 file1
```

Explained:

```
NR==FNR {                         # process file2
    a[$1]=$2                      # hash record using $1 as the key
    next                          # skip to next record
} 
(i=substr($4,1,9)) && (i in a) {  # read the first 9 bytes of $4 to i and search in a
    print $0, a[i]                # output if found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]_]+' '
   FNR==NR { a[$2]=$3 ;next }
   { if ( $5 in a ) $0 = $0 " " a[$5] }
   7
   ' file2 file1
```

Comment:

- use `_` as extra field separator so file names are easier to compare in both file (using only the number part).
- 7 is for fun, it's just a non 0 value -> print the line
- i don't change the field (NF+1, ...) so we keep the original format adding just the referenced number

a smaller oneliner code (optimized for code size) (assuming non empty lines in file1 that are mandatory). if separator are only space, you can remplace [:blank:] by a space char

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]_]+' 'NF==3{a[$2]=$3;next}$0=$0" "a[$5]' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

No `awk` or `sed` needed.  This assumes *file2* is only one line:

```
n="`cut -f 2 file2`" ; while read x ; do echo "$x $n" ; done < file1
```